# TCP/IP data transfer freezes Unity while transferring the data

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, tcpserver

I am working on a unity project where user can send data from client to server using TCP/IP. I am able to send the data. But my unity stalls or freeze until the data got read from the networkstream.

Server Code:Read Data.

```
   public void StartServer (){
        // Start TcpServer background thread        
        tcpListenerThread = new Thread (new ThreadStart(ListenForIncomingRequests));        
        tcpListenerThread.IsBackground = true;      
        tcpListenerThread.Start();


        startServerButton.interactable = false;

        path =  UnityEditor.EditorUtility.SaveFolderPanel ("Any type of File.", "", ""); //  Path.Combine(path,"D:\\Siva\\TCPDownloadfiles");  

    }



    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {        
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) {             
            SendMessage();         
        }   
    }  




    /// <summary>   
    /// Runs in background TcpServerThread; Handles incoming TcpClient requests     
    /// </summary>  
    private void ListenForIncomingRequests () {

        Thread threadForDownloading = new Thread (new ThreadStart(DownloadingStreamData));      
        threadForDownloading.IsBackground = true;       
        threadForDownloading.Start();

        //DownloadingStreamData ();

    }


    private void DownloadingStreamData()
    {
        try {       
            fileCount++;

            int fileNameLen;
            byte[] incomingData = new byte[1024];
            string ext = "";

            // Create listener on localhost port 8052.          
            tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8052);          
            tcpListener.Start();              
            Debug.Log("Server is listening");              
            bytes = new Byte[Int32.MaxValue];  // 2221024           
            while (true) {              
                using (connectedTcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient()) {                    
                    // Get a stream object for reading                  
                    using (stream = connectedTcpClient.GetStream()) {   



                        Debug.Log("Befor Stream Read.........."); 
                        IAsyncResult result = stream.BeginRead(bytes, 0, bytes.Length, MessageReceived,  stream);
                        result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();


                        // Read incoming stream into byte arrary.                       
                        do{
                            //length = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                            //length = s_bytesReceived;

                            Debug.Log("After Stream Read.........."+length); 

                            incomingData = new byte[length];    
                            Array.Copy(bytes, 0, incomingData, 0, length - 4);  

                            // Convert byte array to string message.    
                            fileNameLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(incomingData, 0);
                            string clientMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(incomingData,4, fileNameLen); 
                            ext = Path.GetExtension(clientMessage);

                            //Debug.Log("client message received as: " + clientMessage);            
                            //File.WriteAllBytes(path + "\\temp"+fileCount.ToString()+ext, incomingData);

                            BinaryWriter bWrite = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(path + "\\temp"+fileCount.ToString()+ext, FileMode.Create)); ;
                            bWrite.Write(incomingData, 4 + fileNameLen, length - 4 - fileNameLen);
                            bWrite.Flush();
                            bWrite.Close();

                        } while(stream.DataAvailable); 

                        //Debug.Log("Bytes length2 :>>>"+"   "+fileNameLen +" Incoming data length"  +incomingData.Length);
                        //connectedTcpClient.Close();
                        //stream.Flush();
                        //stream.Close();
                        //Debug.Log("GETTING FILE NAME THROUGH BUFFER ::"+stream);
                    } 

                }

            }       
        }       
        catch (SocketException socketException) {           
            Debug.Log("SocketException " + socketException.ToString());         
        }
    }
```

I tried using stream.BeginRead method but that is throwing exception like Stream/socket was disposed already and trying to access it on client code.

But stream.Read method works as like i expect but it stalls/freeze the unity until it get the data.Please give me some better solution for this issue. Thanks in advance.

Client Code: Sends Data

```
 if (stream.CanWrite) { 
string path = UnityEditor.EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel ("Any type of File.", "", "");
                WWW www = new WWW ("file:///" + path);

                 byte[] fileNameBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(path); 
                 byte[] fileDataBytes = www.bytes;
                 byte[] fileNameLength = BitConverter.GetBytes(fileNameBytes.Length);
                 clientData = new byte[4 + fileNameBytes.Length + fileDataBytes.Length];
                 fileNameLength.CopyTo(clientData, 0);
                 fileNameBytes.CopyTo(clientData, 4);
                 fileDataBytes.CopyTo(clientData, 4 + fileNameBytes.Length);
                 Debug.Log ("FIle sends to server path : "+path);
             //stream.BeginRead(clientData, 0, clientData.Length, MessageReceived,  stream);

             try {
                 stream.Write(clientData, 0, clientData.Length);  
                 //stream.BeginWrite(clientData, 0, clientData.Length, MessageReceived,  stream);
             }catch (Exception e) {             
                 Debug.Log("SocketException " + e.ToString());         
             }
```

Comment: It’s normal to get an exception when the socket is closed in the other end when using async reads. You just need to handle the exception.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I didn't understand please give me a code snippet from the above example.I tried try catch exception also. Still the socket is getting closed.
Server code which i am doing is altogether it is an different thread. But still i don't understand why it halts main thread.

Comment: Then it needs more code. Preferably a [mcve] because this doesn’t show any threading or how it’s called

Comment: Are you doing this in a thread? Or directly in the main thread of Unity? `tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient()` is a blocking call that freezes until a client actually connects...

Comment: Yes this is in thread.I have edited the question again. but i dont understand why  length = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length); blocks main thread.

Comment: If you don't know how many incomming connections could occur, you'd better of using the async sockets. `socket.BeginReceive()` etc. A thread per connection is faster, but less scalable.

Comment: I'm trying to find the keyword "Send" from this thread, but how "...user can send data.."?

Comment: FMETP STREAM is an alternative solution for live streaming purpose.